# Java regex check if certain characters match pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need your help with regex. 
This is my requirement, check string if it starts with 0937, 937 or 63937. Next check if string ONLY contains digits and check if length of characters for 0937 = 11, 937 = 10, 63937 = 12.

So far this is what I've tried:

```
class MyRegex {

static Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^0937[0-9]{11}+$");
static Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^937[0-9]+{10}$");
static Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("^63937[0-9]{12}$");

 public static void main(String []args){

    String phone = "09375126435"; //"639375126439"; // "9375126435";

    System.out.println(validateABSMobileNumber(phone));
 }

 public static boolean validateABSMobileNumber(String phone){
    return p1.matcher(phone).matches() || p2.matcher(phone).matches() || p3.matcher(phone).matches() ;
}

}
```

Sample test cases:

09375126435 = true
0937512643  = false
639375126439 = true
63937512643 = false
9375126439  = true
937512643   = false

But it doesn't run correctly. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Your requirements mean that a regex is not that necessary here. `String.startsWith()` + `StringUtils.isNumeric` + `String.length()` can be used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you explain why?

Comment: `StringUtils` requires an external library, and I see nothing wrong with using regex here.

Comment: `NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(value)` can be used instead of `StringUtils.isNumeric`. No one says a regex is a wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns were counting characters incorrectly.  Use this:

```
static Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^0937[0-9]{7}$");
static Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^937[0-9]{7}$");
static Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("^63937[0-9]{7}$");
```

Comment: Why use 3 different patterns when you can use 1? And why do you think OP solution "counted" characters incorrectly? :)

Comment: This code is readable, and sometimes this is more valuable than having a slick looking (and non maintainable) regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew His original patterns were matching the initial portion _plus_ the entire length of what he wanted.  To put it another way, in the first pattern he wants 11 characters total, but he was matching 11 characters _after_ the initial pattern, for a total of 15 characters.

Comment: So, it is not *patterns* that are to blame, it is a logical error made by OP. And the problem is different in the second regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use only one pattern, something like this:

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^((0937)|(937)|(63937))[0-9]{7}$");
```

This patter include your three cases with the correct length. So if you can have a maintable regex, I recommend you to use a properties file.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.